# Disable all scripts and styles from NextGEN Gallery?

Tags: plugins, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I use nextgen gallery in a multisite. How can I disable all scripts and styles?
These thing are loaded in the code of my site:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css'  href='http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.9995'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06'></script>

<!-- <meta name="NextGEN" version="1.9.7" /> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes care of NextGEN's slideshow and CSS, as well as the Shutter script and CSS that it also enqueues by default.

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpse_82982_removeScripts');
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpse_82982_removeStyles');

function wpse_82982_removeScripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('ngg-slideshow');
    wp_dequeue_script('shutter');
}

function wpse_82982_removeStyles() {
    wp_dequeue_style('NextGEN');
    wp_dequeue_style('shutter');
}
```

But: are you *sure* you want to do that? Maybe you can be a little selective, and only do that on selected pages / posts / categories.

Edit: to remove the commented-out meta tag too, add this filter:

```
add_filter('show_nextgen_version', '__return_null');
```

Comment: i use with Justified Image Grid - Premium WordPress Gallery , so the js and css of nextgen are useless now. Also, if i wont to this action in all of my sites in my multiste what is the code for wp-config.php?

Comment: I'd suggest you [create a minimal plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), then you can easily drop it into any site without modification.

Comment: ok, thnx a lot :)

Comment: Something last, do you know how can i remove and this <!-- <meta name="NextGEN" version="1.9.10" /> -->?

Comment: They give you a free plugin, and you want to remove their credit? Nice...

Comment: i want to remove for security reasons only

Comment: @Alex: see updated answer

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with nextgen version 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Another buyer has created this snippet https://gist.github.com/Davidlab/5134645

The proper way is to
    `define('NGG_SKIP_LOAD_SCRIPTS', true);`

Note that this'll be included in the next version of my plugin.

Comment: How can I disable this nextgen retarded code from custom template? Why dont you use wp_footer hooks? Instead stuff them freaking everywhere and your source code is horrible to understand. If I have jquery UI and jquery already in the head, dont put them again to the footer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nextgen retarded code' exactly? What script are you talking about and are you talking to me? I do use wp_print_footer_scripts hooks and enqueue scripts with the footer set to true. Can you define 'stuffing them freaking everywhere'? My code is long and linear, it's better for me than having zillion classes an 600 small PHP files like NextGEN. I don't put jQuery again in the footer, I don't use jQuery UI either. If you have issues with JIG, contact me from my profile on CodeCanyon from the account you purchased it with, you don't need to edit any code, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Beware something changed in 3.9.0 and my setting of this constant broke all my loops.

Answer (score 0):

In new version of nextGen if you want clean album css you just need

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpse_82982_removeStyles');

function wpse_82982_removeStyles() {
    wp_dequeue_style('nextgen_basic_album_style');
}
```

Comment: that's not acquired, don't forget that nextgen has many different styles with different name.